# boost::python passing argv to C++

Tags: python, boost, command-line-interface, boost-python, argv

I have a C++ project and I want to give a python-API to it - I provide a shared library which the user imports in his python project.
The C++ code parses the CLI, so I need to pass the C++ side (from the python-API) argv as char**, and not as a list.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You can allocate the C array with `new char*[PyList_Size(l)]` and fill it with C copies of Python strings therein, each created with `strdup(PyString_AsString(PyList_GetItem(l, I)))`. `boost::python` might offer shortcuts to implement this, but that will be the general idea.

Comment: Tnx man, but I not familiar with C-API for python, and not fully-understand your explanation... If you have time and can provide a small code example, that's will be awesome

Comment: I've now posted an answer with code that implements the above suggestion using pure Python/C API. It should be easy to adapt to the `boost::python` dialect, or you can leave it as-is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function written using the regular Python/C API (untested). Feel free to adapt to `boost::python` constructs as appropriate:

```
char **list_to_argv_array(PyObject *lst)
{
  assert (PyList_Check(lst));       // use better error handling here
  size_t cnt = PyList_GET_SIZE(lst);
  char **ret = new char*[cnt + 1];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    PyObject *s = PyList_GET_ITEM(lst, i);
    assert (PyString_Check(s));     // likewise
    size_t len = PyString_GET_SIZE(s);
    char *copy = new char[len + 1];
    memcpy(copy, PyString_AS_STRING(s), len + 1);
    ret[i] = copy;
  }
  ret[cnt] = NULL;
  return ret;
}
```

When the array is no longer needed, deallocate it by `delete[]`-ing all the individual members, as well as the array itself.

Comment: Great answer! TnxAlot